# A plugin has overridden some jQuery UI functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

A plugin, namely jEasyUI, has overridden the droppable and draggable functions of jQueryUI. How do I use jQueryUI functions instead?

The jEasyUI ones bring some strange behavior. This relates to a question I asked before ([jQuery & JEasyUI dynamic droppable element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384287/jquery-jeasyui-dynamic-droppable-element)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the order of inclusion in your <head> tag

First put jEasyUI in <script>

After that put JQueryUI in <script>

As per the JavaScript order of deceleration, now the JQueryUI will override similar functions in jEasyUI